El nombre de clase debe ser un objeto válido o una cadena
En mi index tengo este botton que elimina registros en un crud.


<td class="px-4 py-2 border">
  <form action="{{ route('permisos.destroy', $permiso->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
    @csrf @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-400 text-white px-3 py-1 rounded">Eliminar</button>
  </form>
</td>



el cual elimina un registro pero al darle "click", me sale el error Class name must be a valid object or a string.
Este es mi controlador el cual controla mi index, este es el método destroy el cual es el que me esta generando el error.
    public function destroy($id)
    {
            $permisos = Permission::findOrFail($id);
            $permisos->delete();
            return redirect()->route('permisos.index');
    }


Estás seguro que $permiso->id esta siendo cargado correctamente ??? para verificar, en la funcion, podrías imprimir un log y ver si llega dato como tal.

yo creo que faltan mas detalles
